# Kill the [tool-advice] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [tool-advice](/questions/tagged/tool-advice) tag currently only has 35 questions, so it should be fairly easy to retag.  However, I would say almost every single question here is off-topic as well, and in need of closing/deleting.

Such gems include:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654266/suggestion-for-physics-engines-to-simulate-soil-and-real-time-land-changing
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658643/reccomend-an-ide-for-c-development
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324124/looking-for-a-software-to-support-a-business-need

... etc, etc.

Time to break out the close votes!

Comment: close/delete voted all of those. agreed - this is a terrible tag +1

Comment: I propose a tag synonym with [tag:cv-pls]

Comment: @JohannesKuhn - I don't think I follow...

Comment: The tag still exists. Leave it as Trap?

Comment: @LBT was kind of a joke: [tag:cv-pls] is used in the PHP chat to [ask for close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120186/190161)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn - aha!  Never saw that one before, thanks

Comment: @LBT Note that the questions are not taged with it, it is just used so it stand out.

Comment: Apparently @danielhanly.com went through and removed the tag from **all** the questions, so I've gone through his revision history and favorited all the questions from there, so I can go back and delete them later.  That's irritating.

Comment: Ack! Someone removed the tags. I really prefer to just close the questions, then circle back later and delete them if no one improves them.

Comment: It was me... I apologise. Check my revisions history, they're the only things I've edited in a while: http://stackoverflow.com/users/418146/danielhanly-com?tab=activity&sort=revisions

Comment: Everything down to the Custom Markers in Google Maps revision was to do with the tag

Comment: I'm an idiot... sorry.

Comment: @danielhanly.com - no worries, we've got it covered, don't be too hard on yourself

Comment: @danielhanly.com Yep, no worries. They'll get cleaned up. :)